# Create posts, pages and menus in Wordpress MU

Tags: wordpress

I'm using Wordpress (with multisite capabilities enable) to create my network.
When I add a new site, it's needed to create some posts, pages and menus into this new site.
I need to create a default form (with WP Contact Form 7 plugin) too.

While I'm looking for this answer, I'm doing this manually: add the new site, create posts, pages, menus and default contact form, then I give the user and password to new user.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done with a [Must Use Plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins) and the action hook `wpmu_new_blog`.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Create custom content on site creation
 */

add_action( 'wpmu_new_blog', 'custom_items_so_23276440', 10, 6 );

function custom_items_so_23276440( $blog_id, $user_id, $domain, $path, $site_id, $meta )
{
    switch_to_blog( $blog_id );
    $default_page = array(
                    'post_title'   => 'Default title',
                    'post_content' => '<h2>Default content</h2>',
                    'post_status'  => 'publish',
                    'post_type'    => 'page'
                  );

    // insert the post into the database
    wp_insert_post( $default_page );
    restore_current_blog();
}
```

To create the menus, use the functions `wp_create_nav_menu` and `wp_update_nav_menu_item`. I'm not sure about the contact form, you'll have to inspect the database to see how CF7 does it, maybe it has some handy function to create a form programatically...

There's another technique using the file `wp-content/install.php` explained in [How to Create a Custom WordPress Install Package?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/77597/12615)